# Allowing All Pods In AKS Cluster To Talk To One Another

Tags: kubernetes-pod, azure-aks, kubernetes-networking

Trying to find a good way to allow open communications across all my pods in the same node. It's a micro service architecture and want them to interact with each other. Would rather not use a NSG and let this be dynamic. Are there any good patterns out there using K8 networking or ingress controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kubernetes is designed in such a fashion that any pod can talk to any pod. This is possible be default in kubernetes, you dont have to do anything to achieve this.

Comment: So maybe it's the NSG I have in azure trying to protect outside access to the cluster that is being applied to all pod communications as well. I have just a few rules associated to the cluster. Maybe I should use an ingress controller for external communications.

Comment: unless you explicitly block traffic inside the vnet - no. since nsg allows that by default. if you are using the Azure cni